# localStorage responds later than a new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

Upon clicking on a button "**Login**" located in **login.html** page, I am trying to 1) login and 2) retrieve user's data from Firebase database and display them in a new HTML page named **personal_page.html** (other then the page where "**Login**" button is located) which is being opened and loaded again upon clicking "**Login**" button as it is within an `</a>` tag. Here is the retrieval part:

```
btnLogin.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Get email and pass
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPassword.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  // Sign in
  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
  promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));


  let rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Users");
  rootRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on("value", function (snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot;
    user.forEach(function (childsnapshot) {
      var userInfo = childsnapshot.val();
      localStorage.setItem("FirstName", userInfo.first_name);
    })
  })
```

So, what I am doing or at least I want to do is to get this data from database, to keep it in localStorage and when the personal_page.html is loaded to get and display this data. The problem I am facing is that upon clicking the "Login" button, the personal_page.html page is loaded faster than the data is retrieved and stored in localStorage. One of the reasons I doubt it's happening is that I have an asynchronous code here above and that's why its execution is delayed. Any ideas what's going on, how to fix this or maybe an alternative way? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to prevent the default action for the click event on your `<a>` tag and only navigate **after** everything has been loaded. Is that right?

Comment: yes, exactly. The click does two things, first it retrieves the data and stores in localStorage, and second, it opens a new page where this data should be displayed. The second action should be done only after the data is fully stored, otherwise there is no point to open the other page, because its purpose is to show this data.

Comment: You can prevent the default action using `btnLogin.addEventListener("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* the rest of your code */ })`